# Barplot 2 categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I got two categorial variables and I want to plot something like this:

[image: Plot]

Comment: There is only one question here, and is already answered I don't know the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged your question with pandas so I'm going to assume that your data is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Here I'm going to make some data which may or may not resemble your data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

detect = np.array([4e6, 5e5])
no_detect = np.array([3.75e6, 6e5])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([detect, no_detect]).T, columns=['Has Detections', 'No Detections'])
```

pandas has inbuilt plotting routines which makes it easy to achieve the plot you'd like.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df.plot.bar(rot=0, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
ax.set_xlabel('Census')
```

This gave me the following figure:

[image]